# Codeception - How do I change out the request timeout?

Tags: php, codeception

When I try to change the timeout, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Robofile::task() in
>   /Users/.../automated-customer-tests/.../vendor/codeception/robo-paracept/src/MergeReports.php
>   on line 12 ERROR: Call to undefined method Robofile::task()  in
>   /Users/.../automated-customer-tests/.../vendor/codeception/robo-paracept/src/MergeReports.php:12

Script `vendor/bin/robo parallel:all` handling the parallel event returned with error code 255

However, if I can't run parallel test because it continues to timeout, with the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
>   The process "vendor/bin/robo parallel:all" exceeded the timeout of 300
>   seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout method to change timeout value:

```
class RoboFile extends \Robo\Tasks
{

    function test()
    {
        $this->taskParallelExec()
            ->timeout(400)
            ->process('sleep 500')
            ->process('sleep 500')
            ->process('sleep 404')
            ->run();
    }
}
```